# Perform mathematical operation on specific matrix elements using index vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I wanna perform an easy operation on specific elements on a 3D data set based on a 3D mask (containing ones and zeros). The operation I wanna do is divition and since I don't wanna introduce NaN's to my data set, I only wanna perform the divition on elements inside the mask. Also, I'm gonna do this on a large data set with quite big matrices so I wanna avoid for-loops as long as it's possible.

Here's some code:

```
inside_mask = numpy.where(mask_data>0)
```

This gives me a three 1 by 97442 vectors which values corresponds to an index in my mask where I have a "one". I.e vector1[0], vector2[0], vector3[0] is the first element where I have a "one".

Therefore I can do this:

```
for i in range(0,97442):
    row = inside_mask[0][i]
    col = inside_mask[1][i]
    depth = inside_mask[2][i]

    someValue = valueMatrix[row, col, depth]
    calculation[row, col, depth] = signal_data[row, col, depth]/someValue
```

So the question is simple: How can I do this with only elemntwise operations and without the for-loop?

Sincerely, Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use logical indexing.

Example:

```
# Build input:
signal_data = np.ones((3, 3, 3))*2
valueMatrix = signal_data.copy()
valueMatrix[0, 0, 0] = 0
valueMatrix[0, 0, 1] = 0
valueMatrix[0, 1, 0] = 0
valueMatrix[1, 0, 0] = 0
mask_data = valueMatrix

# Calculation:
above_zero = mask_data > 0
calculation = signal_data.copy()
calculation[above_zero] = signal_data[above_zero] / valueMatrix[above_zero]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

myarr = np.random.randint(2,size=[10,10,10]).astype(float)
someValue  = 3
myarr[myarr>0] = myarr[myarr>0]/someValue
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make a sample 2d array:

```
In [51]: data = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,4))                                                                         
In [52]: data                                                                                                        
Out[52]: 
array([[2, 0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2]])
```

a boolean mask of nonzero elements:

```
In [53]: data>0                                                                                                      
Out[53]: 
array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

the where/nonzero indices of those elements:

```
In [54]: idx = np.nonzero(data>0)                                                                                    
In [55]: idx                                                                                                         
Out[55]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

That tuple can be used directly to index `data` (or any array of the same shape):

```
In [56]: data[idx]                                                                                                   
Out[56]: array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

This is the same as using the boolean mask directly:

```
In [57]: data[data>0]                                                                                                
Out[57]: array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

Those nonzero elements can be selected and/or modified

```
In [58]: data[idx] = data[idx] * 2                                                                                   
In [59]: data                                                                                                        
Out[59]: 
array([[4, 0, 2, 4],
       [2, 2, 0, 4],
       [2, 2, 2, 4]])
```

(Since `data` is integer dtype, I did not try to divide, which would create float values.)

`ufunc` like divide, add, etc, have a `where` parameter.  For example to take the inverse of nonzero elements:

```
In [71]: data = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,4)).astype(float)                                                           
In [72]: data                                                                                                        
Out[72]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 2.],
       [1., 0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 2., 2., 1.]])
In [73]: np.divide(1, data, where=data>0, out=data)                                                                  
Out[73]: 
array([[1. , 0. , 0. , 0.5],
       [1. , 0. , 1. , 0.5],
       [0. , 0.5, 0.5, 1. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!